# Delete all email from account

Tags: php, gmail

I'm trying to put together a function in php that will log into gmail and delete all the emails in the inbox.  That's it.  I'm at a bit of a standstill with it and have tried a number of ways to do it including reworking other code to try and get it to work but with limited success.

The most recent being:

```
function deleteEmails($emailAddress, $reportUrl, $reportType)
{
    $result = "error";
    // DOWNLOAD DATA
    // the max time allows for the email to download
    set_time_limit(30000);

    // connect to gmail with your credentials
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = $emailAddress; # e.g somebody@gmail.com
    $password = $superSecretPasswordShhhhhhhh;


    // try to connect
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot download information: ' . imap_last_error());
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
    // if any emails found, iterate through each email
    if($emails)
        {
            $count = 1;

            // for every email...
            foreach($emails as $email_number) 
                {
                    // TRIED BOTH, BUT THE EMAILS WOULDN'T DELETE
                    //imap_delete($inbox,$email_number);
                    imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number,'[Gmail]/Bin');
                    $result = "success";
                }
        } 
    // close the connection
    imap_close($inbox,CL_EXPUNGE);
    return $result;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing or is there a cleaner way to do it?

To answer the question of why:

There is an application that loops a function that downloads email from the account and saves the attached report. This works fine but the problem is that the reports arrive every minute and so when the function is run it could have hundreds of reports to go through. So to clean the backlog before starting the process would be the best thing to keep the inbox clean

The following is the code as it stands.  It works in that it deletes the emails but even if the emails are all gone it runs until I get a server error.  Any ideas what I might be missing?

```
// DELETE ALL EMAILS IN ACCOUNT
```

function deleteEmails($emailAddress)
    {
        $result = "error";
        // DOWNLOAD DATA
        // the max time allows for the email to download
        set_time_limit(30000);

```
    // connect to gmail with your credentials
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = $emailAddress; # e.g somebody@gmail.com
    $password = $superSecretPasswordShhhhh;


    // try to connect
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot download information: ' . imap_last_error());
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');



    // if any emails found, iterate through each email
    if($emails)
        {
            $count = 1;

            // put the newest emails on top
            rsort($emails);


            // for every email...
            foreach($emails as $email_number) 
                {
                    // TESTING BOTH METHODS
                    imap_delete($inbox,$email_number);
                    //imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number,'[Gmail]/Bin');
                    $result = "success";
                }
        } 
    // close the connection
    imap_expunge($inbox);
    imap_close($inbox,CL_EXPUNGE);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Sounds a little suspicious? Why would this be a good thing to do?

Comment: This can easily be done in Gmail itself. Click the check and a little message will come across the top and it will say something like "All **25** conversations on this page are selected. Select all **14113** conversations in Inbox" If you click that then you have selected all them and you can then click the trash and everything would be deleted out of the inbox.

Comment: There is an application that loops a function that downloads email from the account and saves the attached report.  This works fine but the problem is that the reports arrive every minute and so when the function is run it could have hundreds of reports to go through.  So to clean the backlog before starting the process would be the best thing to keep the inbox clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call this before closing the connection:

```
imap_expunge($inbox);
```

This will delete all messages you marked for removal.

Replace `imap_mail_move` with `imap_delete` first though.

Read more about it: http://php.net/imap-expunge

Comment: Thanks, it worked in that it is deleting the emails but I'm still having an issue with a server error.  It seems to be a time out issue but I'm not sure what might be causing it to keep going even when there are no emails left

Comment: Just to point out, the count is being created but nothing's being done with it. I'd consider changing `$count = 1;` to `$count = 0;`, then `++$count;` last thing in the loop.